# Trying code an applet that draw A SierpinskiTriangle with a for loop

Tags: java, geometry

Hi every one so i am trying to write a code that when I run it will draw a  SierpinskiTriangle. The program has to have a for loop which i already have but i have a problem when trying to get the program to complile. it says double cannot be convert to Point2D can anyone help me with this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

public class ST extends JFrame {

    int N = 50000;
    double sqrt3 = Math.sqrt(3);
    double x = 0.0, y = 0.0; 

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ST t = new ST();
    t.add(new JComponent() {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                double r = Math.random();
                double x0, y0;

                if (r < 1./3.) {
                    x0 = 0.0; y0 = 0.0;
                } else if (r < 2./3.) {
                    x0 = 0.0; y0 = 2.0 ; 
                } else {
                    x0 = sqrt3; y0 = 1.0;
                }
                double x = (x0 + x) / 2;
                double y = (y0 + y) / 2;  

                Shape l = new Line2D.Double(x,y);
                g2d.draw(l);

            }
        }
    });

    t.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    t.setSize(220, 300);
    t.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: More details, please. Which line does the error occur?

Comment: ok i have an error on line 20 , 31 and 36

Answer (score 0):

As the Java API at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.Double.html tells, class `Line2D.Double` has two constructors:

```
Line2D.Double(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
```

and

```
Line2D.Double(Point2D p1, Point2D p2)
```

since you specified two parameters, the java compiler assumes the latter one.

Comment: hmmmm ok..is there another way approach this?

Comment: You don't seem to see the point. Have you read the API docs? I hope you agree that a line needs a start point and an end point. So specify x and y coordinates for start and end point - either by passing 4 numbers, or by passing two point objects consisting itself of two numbers, respectively.